# Laravel Blade: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to run javascript functions in an if statemenet with laravel but I receive the following error when trying to do so:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '(' (View: C:\rcms_w\resources\views\frontend\home.blade.php)
```

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if (Auth::user()->roleplay->health_points >= 100) 
        setHealth(1);
    @elseif
        setHealth(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->health_points }});
    @endif

    @if (Auth::user()->roleplay->energy_points >= 100) 
        setEnergy(1, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->energy_points }});
    @elseif
        setEnergy(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->energy_points }}, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->energy_points }});
    @endif

    @if (Auth::user()->roleplay->hygiene_points >= 100) 
        setHygiene(1, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hygiene_points }});
    @elseif
        setHygiene(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hygiene_points }}, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hygiene_points }});
    @endif

    @if (Auth::user()->roleplay->hunger_points >= 100) 
        setHunger(1, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hunger_points }});
    @elseif
        setHunger(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hunger_points }}, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hunger_points }});
    @endif
    </script>
```

Comment: Error at which line no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Your error is not in this code. Is this your home.blade.php?

Comment: @aynber yes it is, the page loads perfectly fine when removing this code. The error is on line `setHealth(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->health_points }});`

Comment: If you take that line out, does the rest work? Interesting that that particular line throws the error when the line above it does not. You may want to check your User and Roleplay models for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this structure:

```
@if (Auth::user()->roleplay->health_points >= 100) 
    setHealth(1);
@elseif
    setHealth(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->health_points }});
@endif
```

which get parsed to

```
<?php if (Auth::user()->roleplay->health_points >= 100) : ?>
    setHealth(1);
<?php elseif: ?>
    setHealth(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->health_points }});
<?php endif; ?>
```

The elseif part requires another statement (comparing something or expecting a boolean).

If you change the `@elseif` to `@else`, it should work.

Your new script will be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if (Auth::user()->roleplay->health_points >= 100) 
        setHealth(1);
    @else
        setHealth(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->health_points }});
    @endif

    @if (Auth::user()->roleplay->energy_points >= 100) 
        setEnergy(1, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->energy_points }});
    @else
        setEnergy(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->energy_points }}, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->energy_points }});
    @endif

    @if (Auth::user()->roleplay->hygiene_points >= 100) 
        setHygiene(1, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hygiene_points }});
    @else
        setHygiene(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hygiene_points }}, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hygiene_points }});
    @endif

    @if (Auth::user()->roleplay->hunger_points >= 100) 
        setHunger(1, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hunger_points }});
    @else
        setHunger(0.{{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hunger_points }}, {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->hunger_points }});
    @endif
</script>
```